# Is it good practice to always end a FORTRAN program with a STOP statement?

Tags: fortran

As the title says, really.

Is there anything against not using stop, like this:

```
PROGRAM myprog
. 
. < do stuff >
.
END PROGRAM myprog
```

rather than using an explicit stop, as in this:

```
PROGRAM myprog
. 
. < do stuff >
.
STOP
END PROGRAM myprog
```

I see a lot of older fortran code that has a `STOP` before the `END PROGRAM` statment, but is it really needed there?

On our Cray machine, having a `STOP` stament at the end of the program writes the string "STOP" to STDERR, which is a bit annoying...

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no reason (I think) to have a stop to indicate normal termination immediately before an `end program`.

Comment: no need for `STOP` before end.. Still you might also check if the compiler has a flag to turn that off.

Comment: Nor there is any reason to put RETURN before the end of every subroutine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code

```
stop
end program
```

is redundant as far as the program return value is concerned in modern Fortran.  A `stop` with no integer or character *stop-code* should return a 0 exit code to the OS if exit codes are supported.  If `end program` is encountered the behavior is the same, returning 0 to the OS.

The difference arises in program output.  As you've noted, `stop` produces output.  The standard (Fortran 2008 cl. 8.4) says

> When an image is terminated by a STOP or ERROR STOP statement, its stop code, if any, is made available
>   in a processor-dependent manner. If any exception (14) is signaling on that image, the processor shall issue a
>   warning indicating which exceptions are signaling; this warning shall be on the unit identified by the named
>   constant ERROR UNIT (13.8.2.8). It is recommended that the stop code is made available by formatted output
>   to the same unit.

This recommends the *stop-code* be made available on standard error, which is where your `STOP` output is coming from.  If you had given a *stop-code* to `stop`, it would have been output with `STOP`.  Additionally, if there are floating point exceptions signalling, you will get additional output on standard error detailing that condition.

If you don't desire the additional output from `stop` and are not using it to return a non-zero error code to the OS, you can omit it from your program.

There is probably a historical reason for the `stop`,`end` ending of the main program, but my brief skimming of a FORTRAN66 manual did not enlighten me.

Comment: Fortran 66 didn't specific the effect of END without STOP or RETURN, so it was implementation dependent.  Certain pre-processing tools which I used insert a STOP ahead of END, possibly in the expectation that it might help diagnose this ancient non-portability.